# Read Excel File From Stream Asp.Net Core WebAPI

Tags: c#, excel, angular, asp.net-web-api, .net-core

I'm working with asp.net core webapi and I want to post an excel file from client (using Angular 2) to my Controller. I've read [Import Excel example](http://www.talkingdotnet.com/import-export-xlsx-asp-net-core/) but what they've done is use an existing file. I want to know how can I read an excel file using **IO.Stream**. Thanks for your help.
I've started read a **.txt** file like this:

```
public string Post()
    {
        var files = Request.Form.Files;
        if(files != null)
        {

            var stream = files[0].OpenReadStream();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);

            string result = reader.ReadToEnd();
            int a;
            return result;
        }
        return "";
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I understand you're trying to use EPPlus library (one of the ports compatible with .NET Core). `ExcelPackage` class has an overload that accepts `Stream` with existing Excel content (only OpenXML-based XLSX):

```
using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(stream)) {
   ...
}
```

Comment: I've just installed it to my project and I've found the overload constructor as you've suggested me. Anyway, Many thanks for your help!